# Which one is correct and natural: "hammer a nail here" or "hammer a nail into here"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which one is correct and natural: *hammer a nail here* or *hammer a nail into here*? For example:

> We need to hammer a nail **here** so that we can hang a picture.
>
> We need to hammer a nail **into** **here** so that we can hang a picture.

If neither is fine, would it more natural to say the following?

> We need to hammer a nail **into this spot** so that we can hang a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither is natural.

One doesn't hammer a nail into a spot. One hammers it into a wall or plank or similar at a particular point.

Thus, prefer:  to **hammer a nail into the wall at this point/spot**.

If you were pointing to the spot, you would just say **here**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you clarify "here" or "into hear"?

Comment: **Into here** is NOT idiomatic.  Possibly **into the wall/plank here**. **Here** equals **at this point** if you are pointing to the spot.